# Avoid stacking of sparse matrices for elementwise multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to perform a elementwise-multiplication of two (scipy) sparse matrices: `A.shape = B.shape = (m,n)`. However, matrix `B` consists of a smaller matrix `B_base` which is stacked horizontally. Obviously, this is is not memory-efficient. Thus, the question: How can I efficiently multiply `A` and `B_base` elementwise without stacking?

Below find a MWE using `sparse.hstack`:

```
from scipy import sparse 

A = sparse.random(m=1000, n=10000, density=0.1, format="csc")
B = sparse.random(m=1000, n=1000, density=0.1, format="csc")
factor_matrix = sparse.hstack([B for i in range(10)], format="csc")

result = A.multiply(factor_matrix)
```

Comment: While for dense arrays, `(A.reshape(m,1000,10)*B_base[:,:,None]).reshape(m,n)` should do it, `sparse` does not have any equivalent - no broadcasting or 3d.  The only alternative is to iterate on slices of `A`, multiply, and then stack, but that's likely to be slower.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I was afraid of that.